# How would I create a currency converter with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a currency converter. I'm using javascript and I have a good foundation but I want to know how to make the converter update in real-time without having to click a button.

How do I make it so that my converter converts from a base currency of M without needing be be within a select element & how do I make the converter update as the user types the number in, rather than having to click a button?

I've tried removing all of the available options for the .currency-1 class and only leaving M, but that still leaves a drop down menu. I want to convert from M to X (USD, GBP, CAD, EUR, etc.)

```js
var crrncy = {
  'M': {
    'USD': 0.80,
    'GBP': 0.65,
    'EUR': 0.77,
    'CAD': 0.95,
    'M': 1
  },
};

var btn = document.querySelector('.calculate-btn');
var baseCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-1');
var secondCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-2');
var amountInput = document.getElementById('amount');
var toShowAmount = document.querySelector('.given-amount');
var toShowBase = document.querySelector('.base-currency');
var toShowSecond = document.querySelector('.second-currency');
var toShowResult = document.querySelector('.final-result');

function convertCurrency(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var amount = amountInput.value;
  var from = baseCurrencyInput.value;
  var to = secondCurrencyInput.value;
  var result = 0;
  
  try{
    if (from == to){
      result = amount;
    } else {
     result = amount * crrncy[from][to];
    }
  } catch(err) {
    result = amount * (1 / crrncy[to][from]);
  }
  
  toShowAmount.innerHTML = amount;
  toShowBase.textContent = from + ' = ';
  toShowSecond.textContent = to;
  toShowResult.textContent = result; 
}

btn.addEventListener('click', convertCurrency);
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="currency-1" required>
          <option>M</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="currency-2" required>
          <option>USD</option>
          <option>GBP</option>
          <option>EUR</option>
          <option>CAD</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2">Sum</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result">
      <p>
        <span class="given-amount"></span> 
        <span class="base-currency"></span>
        <span class="final-result"></span> 
        <span class="second-currency"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I need the user to be able to input X amount (in currency M, no dropdown), select their native currency & have the page calculate the rate as soon as they type in the number.

Comment: look at the 'keypress' event for converting while typing. and in currency-1 if you don't want dropdown, then just use span instead of select element.

Comment: Sajal's answer helped solve the realtime calculations, but changing the select element to span stops the functionality of the converter. How would I go about defining "M" as the base rate?

Comment: where do you set what M should be? if you change from select to span, then you can't use element.value but use element.innerText.

Comment: It's set through document.getElementById('currency-1') right now. Is there a way to set currency1 to the value of M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `eventListner` which is `keyup` so that whenever user types in the required field, it will call the `convertCurrency` function as below:

`amountInput.addEventListener('keyup', convertCurrency);`

**Edit:**

To remove the selection box for `M`, remove the `select` element and replace by either `<p>` or `<span>` tag. After this, you would have to get the this value by using `innerText` as `var from = baseCurrencyInput.innerText;` in the currency converter function.

```js
var crrncy = {
  'M': {
    'USD': 0.80,
    'GBP': 0.65,
    'EUR': 0.77,
    'CAD': 0.95,
    'M': 1
  },
}
var btn = document.querySelector('.calculate-btn');
var baseCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-1');
var secondCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-2');
var amountInput = document.getElementById('amount');
var toShowAmount = document.querySelector('.given-amount');
var toShowBase = document.querySelector('.base-currency');
var toShowSecond = document.querySelector('.second-currency');
var toShowResult = document.querySelector('.final-result');

function convertCurrency(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var amount = amountInput.value;
  var from = baseCurrencyInput.innerText;
  var to = secondCurrencyInput.value;
  var result = 0;

  try {
    if (from == to) {
      result = amount;
    } else {
      result = amount * crrncy[from][to];
    }
  } catch (err) {
    result = amount * (1 / crrncy[to][from]);
  }

  toShowAmount.innerHTML = amount;
  toShowBase.textContent = from + ' = ';
  toShowSecond.textContent = to;
  toShowResult.textContent = result;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', convertCurrency);
amountInput.addEventListener('keyup', convertCurrency);
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
   <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <p id="currency-1">M</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="currency-2" required>
          <option>USD</option>
          <option>GBP</option>
          <option>EUR</option>
          <option>CAD</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2">Sum</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result">
      <p>
        <span class="given-amount"></span> 
        <span class="base-currency"></span>
        <span class="final-result"></span> 
        <span class="second-currency"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Do you know what I need to do to have it use M as a base rate by default so that I can remove the selection box?

Comment: You my friend, are an absolute wizard! You have my thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var crrncy = {
  'M': {
    'USD': 0.80,
    'GBP': 0.65,
    'EUR': 0.77,
    'CAD': 0.95,
    'M': 1
  },
};

var btn = document.querySelector('.calculate-btn');
var baseCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-1');
var secondCurrencyInput = document.getElementById('currency-2');
var amountInput = document.getElementById('amount');
var toShowAmount = document.querySelector('.given-amount');
var toShowBase = document.querySelector('.base-currency');
var toShowSecond = document.querySelector('.second-currency');
var toShowResult = document.querySelector('.final-result');

function convertCurrency(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var amount = amountInput.value;
  var from = baseCurrencyInput.value;
  var to = secondCurrencyInput.value;
  var result = 0;
  
  try{
    if (from == to){
      result = amount;
    } else {
     result = amount * crrncy[from][to];
    }
  } catch(err) {
    result = amount * (1 / crrncy[to][from]);
  }
  
  toShowAmount.innerHTML = amount;
  toShowBase.textContent = from + ' = ';
  toShowSecond.textContent = to;
  toShowResult.textContent = result; 
}

btn.addEventListener('click', convertCurrency);

$('#amount').keyup(function(event){
convertCurrency(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="currency-1" required>
          <option>M</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="currency-2" required>
          <option>USD</option>
          <option>GBP</option>
          <option>EUR</option>
          <option>CAD</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2">Sum</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result">
      <p>
        <span class="given-amount"></span> 
        <span class="base-currency"></span>
        <span class="final-result"></span> 
        <span class="second-currency"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```